# Nested Resource Dictionary in separate library

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

My question is very similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750450/how-can-i-import-a-deep-hierarchy-of-merged-dictionaries-with-1-resourcedictiona)

I have a solution with a number of projects. The are two that are relevant: a class library that contains a WPF window and a project with all the WPF styles in it.

**Class Library with the window in Project 1**

The Window's merged dictionary is something like:

```
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/StyleAssembly;component/CommonStyle.xaml"/>
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 

            //other styles here
```

The CommonStyle.xaml in **Project 2**:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Components/Type/CheckBox.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

That results in errors like:

> {"Cannot locate resource 'components/type/checkbox.xaml'."}

However, if I create a CommonStyle.xaml in Project 1 and reference the same control styles from Project 2 then it works.

How do I make that highest level xaml file (CommonStyle.xaml) work from the Project 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently unable to test this, however I hope it should work.

Rather than a rooted path, use a relative path in Project 2, i.e.

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Components/Type/CheckBox.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

You may also use `..` as required to navigate up to a relative directory (depending upon the location of `CommonStyle.xaml`), e.g.

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../Components/Type/CheckBox.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

I believe when you use a rooted path (starting with `/`) it will look for `CheckBox.xaml` in the root of the project where you use `CommonStyle.xaml` rather than relative to the location of `CommonStyle.xaml`.

**Additional Explanation**

From you have described, it seems you have the following structure:

```
- Project 1
  - Window.xaml
- Project 2
  - CommonStyle.xaml
  - Components
    - Type
      - CheckBox.xaml
```

When `CommonStyle.xaml` refers to `/` it is normally referring to the root of Project 2, however when you merge this into `Window.xaml` the `/` would now refer to the root of Project 1, subsequently it is unable to locate `Components/Type/CheckBox.xaml`.

By removing the `/` it will now look for `Components/Type/CheckBox.xaml` relative to the location of `CommonStyle.xaml` which it is able to do.

Comment: You are  entirely correct, but I am still somewhat confused.  The path to the checkbox in the project structure is ProjectRoot/Components/Type/CheckBox  and the CommonStyles is at the root level.  So wasn't that the same location as the relative path?

Comment: @D.. I've updated my answer with some explanation of what I believe to be happening

Comment: Now it makes perfect sense and I learned something important about merged dictionaries.  Thanks!