# How to use Resource Dictionary efficiently in all parts of project

Tags: c#, wpf, optimization, static, resourcedictionary

I am using resource dictionary(same dictionary) in many converters as a local variable.

```
var DeignerDictionary = new ResourceDictionary
{
  Source = new Uri(path)
};
```

Each time I am creates a new instance and the memory goes very high in the application.

Then I have moved the resource dictionary into a static field and I am reusing the dictionary , but the styles are not rendered properly.

```
public class resourceDictionaryProvider{
    public readonly ResourceDictionary StaticDictionary =
    new ResourceDictionar {Source = new Uri(path)};
}
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong,Please provide your suggestions.

The issue occurs after changed the ResourceDictionary as static only.But the following code works fine.

```
public class resourceDictionaryProvider{
    public static readonly ResourceDictionary StaticDictionary =
    new ResourceDictionar {Source = new Uri(path)};
}
```

Now I am creating an instance for resourceDictionaryProvider class and it works fine,But I don't want to create instances So only I have changed it to static.

What is the problem with the static keyword here?

Comment: You shouldn't instantiate ResourceDictionaries in code-behind. They should instead be declared in XAML files, and (if necessary) be accessed from code behind.

Comment: You can nest resource dictionaries in other resource dictionaries using the Source attribute as explainen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023671/nested-resource-dictionary-in-separate-library. The App.xaml contains a resource dictionary that is going to be loaded automatically with the application so, what you include or reference there is available to use app wide.

Comment: The problem he's trying to address is a well known issue with resource dictionary instances (major resource hog as it'll recreated dictionaries including all nested ones each time they get referenced through a control) - he's trying to use SharedResourceDictionary essentially. The question is valid and it'd be nice to see an actual answer to this.

Comment: I can add to the solution provided by Daniel Leiszen, that you can also add a ResourceDictionary outside of  App.xaml, by calling Application.Current.Resources.Add(). That can be useful in plugins. Be aware -  Application.Current is null in tests.

Answer (score 3):

This is a well known problem with WPF ResourceDictionaries. The solution would be to implement a SharedResourceDictionary construct on your own which prevents re-instantiation of the resources on each use. Take a look at this link : [WPF SharedResourceDictionary](https://github.com/indexzero/bruce-wayne/blob/master/wpf-samples/WpfSamples/Controls/SharedResourceDictionary.cs) for an awesome implementation of the SharedResourceDictionary construct.( All credits to the author )

Comment: one more implementation with a bit explanation: http://www.wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues you need to address:

1. The resource dictionaries can be shared across the modules of your project or solution;
2. It would be handy to have design time resource dictionary to assist with the styling settings.

To solve the issue #1, it's easy to add your resource dictionaries to the App.xaml file, and then they will be instantiated once, and will be available to the entire project, like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary
                 Source="pack://application:,,,/Themes;component/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

To solve the issue #2, you need a workaround solution that the resource dictionary is instantiated at the design time only. Check out [Design time resource dictionary](http://blog.oliver-lohmann.me/post/design-time-wpf-xaml-resource-dictionaries/)

and then, you can use the DesignTimeResourceDictionary on your UIs, like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <designer:DesignTimeResourceDictionary
                 Source="pack://application:,,,/Themes;component/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```